# dynamic mathjax with react.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mathjax, reactjs

I tried to combine the markdown example on the [react.js](http://facebook.github.io/react/index.html) page and tried to have it render equations with mathjax. ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrcactu5/kut6d/2/))

Ideally it would take in an input

```
 Type some *markd**o**wn* here! $$ int $$
```

and return the integral sign

> Type some *markd***o***wn* here! ∫

The react.js code is taken directly from Facebook's page.  I hope I called `MathJax.Hub.Queue` in the correct place -- their docs have a discussion of [dynamic MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/dynamic.html) :

```js
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var converter = new Showdown.converter();

var MarkdownEditor = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {value: 'Type some *markdown* here! \\\( \int \\\)'};
  },
  handleChange: function() {
    this.setState({value: this.refs.textarea.getDOMNode().value});
  },
  render: function() {
    console.log(this.state.value);
    return (
      <div className="MarkdownEditor">
        <h3>Input</h3>
        <textarea
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          ref="textarea"
          id="input"
          defaultValue={this.state.value} />
        <h3>Output</h3>
        <div
          className="content"
          id="output"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: converter.makeHtml(this.state.value)
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"output"]);
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<MarkdownEditor />,  document.getElementById('content'))
```

There is a similar example on the [MathJax](http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-dynamic-2.html) page that handles equations but not markdown.

Comment: Probably you should try KaTeX, which seems much more friendly to React.

Answer (score 4):

Your placement of the `MathJax.Hub.Queue` function is incorrect.  Note that it follows the `return` statement, so it never gets performed (since the function returns before getting to it).  The documentation for the `render()` method of the [React.js](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) documentation suggests that it should not modify the DOM, so you don't want to do the typeset at this point anyway.  And since you are returning the HTML string, it hasn't been added to the DOM yet anyway, so it would not be there for MathJax to process anyway.  The documentation suggests that `componentDidMount()` and `componentDidUpdate()` are the places where you should have MathJax typeset the new mathematical content.

I've adjusted your [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kut6d/4/) to include the changes.

Note also that Markdown is going to interact with your backslashes, so it removes the ones for the math delimiters `\(...\)` and you just get `(...)`, so MathJa won't see them.  I've reconfigured MathJax using `MathJax.Hub.Config()` to use dollar sign delimiters `$...$` for in-line math (and the default `$$...$$` for displayed math).  Otherwise you will need to type `\\(...\\)` to get the backslashes into the Markdown output where MathJax can see them (and `\\\\( \int \\\\)` in your initial string).  You can, of course, configure MathJax to use whatever delimiters you want, but dollars are the plain TeX approach.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/kut6d/4/] the above jsfiddle is not working. Can you please update it.

Comment: @AkhilRaghav, There are now several MathJax/React integrations, so you don't have to roll your own.  See, for example, [mathjax-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjax-react), which uses MathJax v3.  There are other older ones for MathJax v2.

Comment: [https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-monad-98ewn?file=/src/MAthjax.js:1125-1135] please refer this code sandbox link as I was trying create a function and convert into mathjax expression where I am failing in some point please help by looking in it