# How can I insert Latex with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mathjax

I have checked out the following fiddle for some insight in to using Latex with AngularJS (http://jsfiddle.net/spicyj/YpqVp/) However, Everything is interpreted as a math formula. What if I want to type some text, along with a math formula? For example, what If I want to write the following inside the `input` in the fiddle example:

"This is an equation: E = mc^2"

If I use the code in the fiddle, then the output looks like this:

*Thisisanequation:E=mc^2*

I'm not exactly sure how I can modify this code so I can enter text AND math formula. Any ideas?

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html) contains examples of how to integrate MJ into HTML. Have you tried these?

Comment: Agreed. Try what @Jongware suggest, but I think you might have more success not coupling mathjax and angular so tightly. In my experience, mathjax is great at what it does, but does not play so well with others.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774855/dynamic-mathjax-with-react-js

Comment: Not knowing much about MathJax specifically, you must "somehow" let the interpreter know, what's formula and what isnt. Sometihng like Input "This is an equation: $E = mc^2$".  If MathJAx has a way to interpret such a thing automatically, this would be the way to go. If it doesnt, you could split your input by the separator ($) and create several `<sctipt math/jax>` elements

Answer (score 1):

```
\text{this is an equation:} x = \frac{5}{4} \div \frac{1}{6}
```